# Does binary log loss exclude one part of equation based on y?

Tags: python, machine-learning, logistic-regression, sklearn-pandas, cross-entropy

Assuming the log loss equation to be:

`logLoss=−(1/N)*∑_{i=1}^N (yi(log(pi))+(1−yi)log(1−pi))`

where `N` is number of samples, `yi...yiN` is the actual value of the dependent variable, and `pi...piN` is the predicted likelihood from logistic regression

How I am looking at it:

if `yi = 0` then the first part `yi(logpi) = 0`

Alternatively, if `yi = 1` then the second part `(1−yi)log(1−pi) = 0`

So now, depending on the value of `y` one part of the equation is excluded. Am I understanding this correctly?

My ultimate goal is to understand how to interpret the results of log loss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are on the right track. Keeping in mind that `p_i=P(y_i=1)`, basically the idea is that the loss function needs to be defined in such a way that it penalizes the tuples for which the prediction does not match the actual label (e.g., when `y_i=1` but `p_i` is low, taken care of by the `yi(logpi)` part, OR when `y_i=0` but `p_i` is high, taken care of by the `(1-yi)log(1-pi)` part) and at the same time it should not penalize the tuples much for which the prediction matches the actual label (e.g., when `y_i=1` and `p_i` is high OR when `y_i=0` and `p_i` is low).

The loss function for logistic regression (`cross entropy`) exactly addresses the above desired property of the loss function, as can be seen from the following figure.

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much. It's not as intuitive as a simple accuracy score. But I get how it's penalizing inaccuracy depending on p_i